# Как в React сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался другой компонент

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Как в React сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку button в браузере открывался другой компонент? Например, был я на компоненте App, а при нажатии на кнопку попадаем в компонент App2. И сделать это нужно, обязательно используя маршрутизацию Route.

Answer (score 0):

[React-router-dom в помощь](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его, как принятый.